# Write to the same file with different processes in order of occurence

Tags: c, linux, process

I am working on a UNIX based operating system (Lubuntu 14.10. I have several processes that need to print a message to the same file and to the std output.

When I print my message to the screen, it works the way I want, in the order of occurence. E.g:

```
Process1_message1
Process2_message1
Process3_message1
Process1_message2
Process2_message2
Process3_message2
...
```

However, when I check the output file it is like below:

```
Process1_message1
Process1_message2
Process2_message1
Process2_message2
Process3_message1
Process3_message2
...
```

I use `fprintf(FILE *ptr, char *str)` to write the message to the file.

**Note:** I opened the file with following format in the main process:

```
fptr=fopen("output.txt", "a");
```

where `fptr` is a global `FILE *`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have shown no code to illustrate how _processes_ are implemented.  Without seeing your code, it will be difficult to identify the problem.  If by _processes_ you mean threads, then the nature of threads (i.e. asynchronous) could possibly explain this behavior.

Comment: @ryyker - He doesn't need to.  `fprintf()` isn't atomic, so multiple processes using it to write to a file are quite likely to see interleaved output.  `write()` **is** atomic.

Comment: @ryyker: I mean processes by processes :) They were forked and that is all about it. It is a simple fork operation and then printing. I have solved the problem by using fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END) every time right before The fprint() line.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Please, check my solution described above. It doesn't seem like as good as the one you suggested. But it is simple :) And I was able to use fprintf() still.

Comment: If it works, it works.  You're still dependent upon the internal implementation of `fprintf()` to avoid multiple `write()` calls, but if you're always seeing proper output where before you weren't, it's working.  One thing to be aware of, though, `fprintf( fptr, str );` isn't safe if `str` has any `%` characters in it as they'd be interpreted as part of a format string.  `fprintf( fptr, "%s", str ):` is safe - but it might also trigger multiple calls to `write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing buffers is different in stdio when you are writing to a terminal (`isatty(fptr)` ---see **isatty(3)**--- returns `true`) than when you output to a file.  For a file, **stdio** output only does a **write(2)** system call when the buffer is filled up and this makes all the messages to appear together (as each buffer flushes out on exit, they fill up in one single output buffer)  On ttys, output is flushed when buffer fills up *or when a `\n` char is output to the buffer* (as a compromise on buffering/non buffering)

You can force buffer flushing with `fflush(fptr);` after `fprintf(fptr, ...);` or even do `fflush(NULL);` (which flushes all output buffers in one call).

But, be carefull as *the writes are the ones that control the atomicity of calls* (not the fprintf calls) so, if you have to write several pages of output in one fprintf call, be ready to accept messed output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Luis Colorado. I will definitely try fflush() which I have never used before. And I guess, I need to learn more about "atomicity of calls". :)

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf()` isn't going to work.  It's prone being translated into multiple calls to `write()` to actually write out the data, exactly like you posted.  You call `fprintf()` once, and under the covers it makes multiple calls to `write()` to actually write the data into the file.

You need to use `open( filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0600 )`, and write data something like this in order to **ensure** you only call `write()` once, which is guaranteed to be atomic:

```
ssize_t myprintf( int fd, const char *fmt, ... )
{
    char buffer[ 1024 ];
    ssize_t bytesWritten;
    va_list argp;
    va_start( argp, fmt );
    int bytes = vsnprintf( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), fmt, argp );
    if ( bytes < sizeof( buffer ) )
    {
        bytesWritten = write( fd, buffer, bytes );
    }
    // buffer was too small, get a bigger one
    else
    {
        char *bufptr = malloc( bytes + 1 );
        bytes = vsnprintf( bufptr, bytes + 1, fmp, argp );
        bytesWritten = write( fd, bufptr, bytes );
        free( bufptr );
    }

    return( bytesWritten );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your problem is that the file output is fully buffered, so the output from each process doesn't appear until the standard I/O buffer for the stream (in that process) is full.

You can probably work around it sufficiently by setting line buffering:

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("output.txt", "a");
if (fptr != 0)
{
    setvbuf(fptr, 0, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);
    …code using fptr — including your fork() calls…
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Every time a process writes a line to the buffer, it will be flushed.  You might run into problems if your output lines are longer than BUFSIZ; then you might want to increase the size passed to `setvbuf()` to the largest line length you need written atomically.

If that still isn't good enough, or if you need to be able to write groups of lines at one time, you'll have to go to a solution using file descriptors as in [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29882175/15168).  You might want to look at the `O_SYNC` and `O_DSYNC` options to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).